# `Failed integrity metadata check.` in JavaFX WebView, ignores SystemProp

Tags: java, javafx, kotlin, webkit, javafx-8

I am trying to open a webview to Microsoft's auth v2. Loads fine in a browser, but in JavaFX's WebView (JDK 8) the page is blank. Once I turned on console output, I see many lines such as for both CSS and JS.

`[null:0] Cannot load stylesheet https://secure.aadcdn.microsoftonline-p.com/ests/2.1.8148.16/content/cdnbundles/converged.v2.login.min_t7iocdq0wq2qh0nv233jig2.css. Failed integrity metadata check.`

I am relatively sure that the issue is with CORS (I am loading `microsoftonline.com` and the resources are on `microsoftonline-p.com`). I've tried every possible fix that I can think of, or find online.

I have tried setting all of these

```
engine.setJavaScriptEnabled(true)

engine.setUserAgent("AppleWebKit/537.44")

System.setProperty("sun.net.http.allowRestrictedHeaders", "true")
```

I've also set the Property via `-Dsun.net.http.allowRestrictedHeaders=true` in `VMOptions` ( as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44905264/cannot-sign-in-to-google-in-javafx-webview) ) and from the JavaFX issue [JDK-8096797](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8096797)

The property shows up as set:

```
println(System.getProperty("sun.net.http.allowRestrictedHeaders"))
```

yields `true` on the console printout.

Still no change, ever in the page output, it is always a white, blank screen, and the same errors from the web console.

I think I found the [trouble lines in WebKit(see `matchIntegrityMetadata`)](https://github.com/WebKit/webkit/blob/89c28d471fae35f1788a0f857067896a10af8974/Source/WebCore/loader/SubresourceIntegrity.cpp) even, but that didn't help me solve the problem any, because I don't know how to disable the *integrityCheck*.

This really, really has me stumped. Any help is *very* appreciated.

For reference, here is the entire method:

```
private fun WebView.authWindow(provider: Oath2Account){
    engine.setUserAgent("AppleWebKit/537.44")
    engine.setJavaScriptEnabled(true)
    URLPermission("https://*.com")
    System.setProperty("sun.net.http.allowRestrictedHeaders", "true")

    Platform.runLater {
        engine.userDataDirectory = File("C:\\users\\eric\\javafx_tmp")
        engine.setOnError { println("IN PAGE ERROR --> $it") }
        engine.setOnAlert { println("IN PAGE ALERT --> $it") }
        engine.setConfirmHandler { println("IN PAGE CONFIRM HANDLER --> $it")
        true
        }
        engine.setCreatePopupHandler { println("IN PAGE POPUP --> $it")
        engine}
        engine.setOnResized {   println("IN PAGE RESIZED --> $it") }
        engine.setOnStatusChanged {   println("IN PAGE STATUS CHANGED --> $it")
            println("\t${it.data}")
            println("\t${it.source}")
            println("\t${it.eventType}")
            println("\t${it.target}")
            println("\t${it.isConsumed}")

        }
        engine.setOnVisibilityChanged { println("IN PAGE VISIBILITY CHANGED --> $it") }
        engine.setPromptHandler { println("IN PAGE PROMPTED --> $it")
        "HELLO"}
        println("JavaScript engine status: ${engine.isJavaScriptEnabled}")

        println("engine is loading $loadURL")
        engine.locationProperty().addListener { observable, oldLocation, newLocation->
            println("observable=$observable\noldLocation=$oldLocation\nnewLocation=$newLocation")
            //          if (newLocation.startsWith("urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob")) {
            //              val code:get
            //              val title:from
            //              val accessToken = service.getAccessToken(verifier)
            //              doSomething(accessToken.getAccessToken())
            //          }
        }
        com.sun.javafx.webkit.WebConsoleListener.setDefaultListener { webview, message, lineNumber, sourceId -> println("Console: [$sourceId:$lineNumber] $message") }
        engine.setOnError({ event -> System.out.println(event.getMessage()) })
        try{
        engine.load(loadURL )
    } catch (e: IOException) {
        println("caught error:")
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Which OS do you use? I have similar problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52747674/javafx-open-login-microsoftonline-com-page-in-webview-component

Comment: Replied to your post below as well, it is Windows 10 1803.

Answer (score 1):

This confirms my answer at:[Javafx - open login.microsoftonline.com page in webview component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52747674/javafx-open-login-microsoftonline-com-page-in-webview-component/53617567#53617567)

The critical point is external script/link integrity fails. This is not a platform browser issue, JavaFX (OpenJFK) relies on an embedded webkit engine.

The regression happened between version 40 and version 172 on windows JDK 8. It's working fine with Oracle JDK 9.0.4 It's not working with Oracle JDK 11

More details at: https://github.com/mguessan/davmail/issues/12

=> Update: issue confirmed by OpenJFX team on Windows and Linux, 
see:
https://github.com/javafxports/openjdk-jfx/issues/230
and
[WebView] Sub-resource integrity check fails on Windows and Linux
https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8219917

=> Updated answer: implemented to override Microsoft form content and disable integrity check. This is not a fix of the webkit bug, just a workaround

```
try {
    URL.setURLStreamHandlerFactory(new URLStreamHandlerFactory() {
        @Override
        public URLStreamHandler createURLStreamHandler(String protocol) {
            if ("https".equals(protocol)) {
                return new sun.net.www.protocol.https.Handler() {
                    @Override
                    protected URLConnection openConnection(URL url, Proxy proxy) throws IOException {
                        System.out.println("openConnection " + url);

                        if (url.toExternalForm().endsWith("/common/handlers/watson")) {
                            System.out.println("Failed: form calls watson");
                        }
                        final HttpsURLConnectionImpl httpsURLConnection = (HttpsURLConnectionImpl) super.openConnection(url, proxy);
                        if ("login.microsoftonline.com".equals(url.getHost())
                                && "/common/oauth2/authorize".equals(url.getPath())) {

                            return new URLConnection(url) {
                                @Override
                                public void connect() throws IOException {
                                    httpsURLConnection.connect();
                                }

                                public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
                                    byte[] content = readFully(httpsURLConnection.getInputStream());
                                    String contentAsString = new String(content, "UTF-8");
                                    System.out.println(contentAsString);
                                    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                                    baos.write(contentAsString.replaceAll("integrity", "integrity.disabled").getBytes("UTF-8"));
                                    return new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray());
                                }

                                public OutputStream getOutputStream() throws IOException {
                                    return httpsURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                                }

                            };

                        } else {
                            return httpsURLConnection;
                        }
                    }

                };
            }
            return null;
        }
    });
} catch (Throwable t) {
    System.out.println("Unable to register custom protocol handler");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out that web view is using webkit engine for mac os/ linux os and IE engine for windows machines. I have similar issue [Javafx - open login.microsoftonline.com page in webview component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52747674/javafx-open-login-microsoftonline-com-page-in-webview-component). WebView on mac os is working fine but there is problem on windows machines. When I was investigating this issue I find out that there is problem in this IE engine. I have access to few machines with different version of IE 11 installed on. On machines with `update version 11.0.85` I wasn't able to open this site, but when I tried on machine with `update version 11.0.90` the problem doesn't exist anymore. So if you are using Windows OS please try to update IE version maybe it will solve your problem.

Comment: Hum, interesting I have the IE feature entirely disabled (via Windows Add/Remove features), I've been using Edge and Chrome (for normal browsing).

Comment: I also disabled IE in my OS but probably the IE engine is somewhere in system? Not sure. Try to enable IE and upodate it maybe it would help. I decided to change approach and for authentication I use python with cefpython library and when user is authenticated I run java from python. I know that it isn't the most elegant way to do this but with this solution I'm independend from OS browser

Answer (score 0):

If anyone still having this problem, then you can solve this by updating your JDK or JRE version to 1.8.0_281 or above.