# WebConsoleListener IllegalAccessError in JavaFX 12

Tags: javafx

I recently downloaded the latest JavaFX SDK 12 and I wish to intercept Console Messages in my JavaFX WebView.

So, I have this

```
WebConsoleListener.setDefaultListener((webView, message, lineNumber, sourceId) -> {
       //////// I am listening for a specific console message here in my 
      ///webview
  });
```

but I keep getting

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class rumbler.launcher.ApplicationLoader (in unnamed module @0x5c4c6905) cannot access class com.sun.javafx.webkit.WebConsoleListener (in module javafx.web) because module javafx.web does not export com.sun.javafx.webkit to unnamed module @0x5c4c6905
```

Here is my `build.gradle` file

```
javafx {
    version = "12.0.1"
    modules = ['javafx.base', 'javafx.controls', 'javafx.web']
}
```

Here are my  `VM OPTIONS`

```
--module-path "path_to_\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\lib" --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml,javafx.web,javafx.base
```

.Am I missing something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using private API, which is not advised.

Anyway, the error message is quite clear:

> module javafx.web does not export com.sun.javafx.webkit to unnamed module @0x5c4c6905

Whenever you want to access some non-exposed package from your project (either modular on non-modular), you need to use `--add-exports`:

> The command line option `--add-exports $module/$package=$readingmodule` exports `$package` of `$module` to `$readingmodule`. Code in `$readingmodule` can hence access all public types in `$package` but other modules can not. [[source](https://blog.codefx.org/java/five-command-line-options-hack-java-module-system/#Accessing-Internal-APIs-With--add-exports)].

So in this case, the solution is straight forward:

```
--add-exports javafx.web/com.sun.javafx.webkit=ALL-UNNAMED \
--module-path "path_to_\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\lib" \
--add-modules javafx.web,javafx.fxml
```

Comment: Note: when adding exports at the command line: if your application provides a `module-info.java` file, then use the name of your application module from the `module-info.java` file, instead of `ALL-UNNAMED`. For more info, see the the related question: [How to get the JavaFx WebEngine to report errors in details?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69637166/how-to-get-the-javafx-webengine-to-report-errors-in-details/69645513#69645513).

Comment: To address "You are using private API, which is not advised."
I want to mention related question "[What is the public API for getting JavaFX WebView console events?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55072824)", which I believe is the better canonical question/answer. (TL;DR: no code API available in 2022, but logging framework can be configured to emit same messages)