# Refresh WebView contents from a JS bridge in JavaFX

Tags: javascript, java, javafx, javafx-webengine

I am creating an AppDrawer (all in one place to launch shortcuts).

My `JSCallBack` bridge class has a method that should delete a shortcut, then refresh the page.  But, it is unable to successfully refresh the page.

*AppDrawerMain.java*

```
public class AppDrawerMain extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(AppDrawerMain.class.getResource("main.fxml"));
        Parent root = (Parent) fxmlLoader.load();

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 1280, 720);
        String css = this.getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm();
        scene.getStylesheets().add(css);
        stage.setTitle("Hello!");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

*AppDrawerController.java*

```
public class AppDrawerController implements Initializable {
    @FXML
    private Button refreshButton;

    @FXML
    private WebView webView;

    WebEngine webEngine;
    JSCallBack jsCallBack;
    
    //this function essentially generates the html code for the webview
    public String loadApps(){
        return "<div class=\"container\"><img src=\"file:/"+imagePath+"\"/><p class=\"title\">"+displayName+"</p><div class=\"overlay\"></div><div class=\"button-open\" onclick=\"app.processOnClickOpen(\'"+id+"\')\"><a href=\"#\"> Open </a></div><div class=\"button-option\" onclick=\"app.processOnClickOption(\'"+id+"\')\"><a href=\"#\"> Edit </a></div></div>"
    }
   
    //refresh the page
    private void refreshPage(String html){
        webEngine.loadContent(html);
        webEngine.reload();
    }

    @SneakyThrows
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {
        refreshButton.setOnAction(event -> {
            refreshPage(loadApps());
        });
        webEngine = webView.getEngine();
        webEngine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue)-> {
            if (newValue == Worker.State.SUCCEEDED) {
                JSObject jsObject = (JSObject) webEngine.executeScript("window");
                jsCallBack = new JSCallBack(webEngine); //declared this way to avoid GC
                jsObject.setMember("app", jsCallBack);
            }
        });
        webEngine.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        var html = loadApps();
        webEngine.loadContent(html);
    }

    //The bridge class
    public class JSCallBack {
        protected JSCallBack() {}

        //no refresh needed here
        public void processOnClickOpen(String id) {
            log("Before open"); 
            onAppOpen(id);
            log("After open");
        }

        //The part that isnt working
        public void processOnClickOption(String id) {
            //deleting the apps works fine
            webEngine.loadContent(loadApps()+loadApps()); //trying to refresh the page isnt fine
            webEngine.reload();           
        }  
    }
}
```

The problem I am having is here:

```
public void processOnClickOption(String id) {          
    //refreshPage(loadApps()+loadApps()) (not working either)
    //refreshButton.fire() (not working either)
    webEngine.loadContent(loadApps()+loadApps()); //trying to refresh the page isnt fine
    webEngine.reload(); //not working   
}
```

1. I tried adding `location.reload()` to the JavaScript function in the script itself, but it did not work.
2. I tried adding the `refreshButton.fire()` to the `processOnClickOption()`, which should reload the page if clicked on manually, but it did work either.
3. I tried to set a new WebEngine in the bridge class itself. Also, it did not work.
4. I added a log to see if there was an issue with threading, but `WebEngine` mentions that it was on the JavaFX Application thread, so that is not the problem either.

This is the main `WebView`:

[image: webview]

If I click on the edit button, it should remove it from the `WebView` and refresh the page like this expected outcome:

[image: outcome]

Unfortunately, after clicking the edit button it will delete the files on the backend side, but the WebView is not refreshed, so the app stays there. I would like to get help on this.

Comment: Related [example for Java/WebView JavaScript interaction](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74310505/1155209).

Comment: @jewelsea I have fixed the code to make it more minimal and reproducible. Regarding your comment on the styleSheet, it seems to be able to read both stylesheets.

Comment: You don't need to call `reload` on the `WebEngine`.  Calling `loadContent` with new content alone is enough to have it load a new document.  I don't think that is your core issue though (I haven't had a chance to try your code).

Comment: Do you have a modular app?  Do you define a `module-info.java`?  If so, do you open the module to `javafx.web` as noted in the [`WebEngine` documentation](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/19/javafx.web/javafx/scene/web/WebEngine.html) section "Deploying an Application as a Module".

Comment: You can get [debug info in WebView you can use the (caution internal API) WebConsoleListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57167872/webconsolelistener-illegalaccesserror-in-javafx-12). Also see related info and [JavaFX 8 WebEngine: How to get console.log() from javascript to System.out in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28687640/javafx-8-webengine-how-to-get-console-log-from-javascript-to-system-out-in-ja). I haven't tried the solution from the JavaFX 8 question.

Comment: Maybe the `a` element in the JavaScript is causing the engine to load the anchor (which points to the existing page rather than your newly loaded page), reloading the existing page.  See [Including both href and onclick to HTML <a> tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14867558/including-both-href-and-onclick-to-html-a-tag).  Maybe get rid of the `<a>` element and just put its text directly in the `div` that you defined your `onclick` handler for (I did not try this, just speculating).

Comment: Implementing this in HTML/JS and displaying it in a `WebView` seems a strange way to go. Why not just implement it all in JavaFX? Anyway, either way, please create and post a [mre].